# Border width in percentage

Tags: html, css

Can i add border-width in percentage?
I've got code like this

HTML

```
<div id="all"></div>
```

CSS

```
#all{
width:96%;
border:1% solid #000;//not working
padding:1%;
}
```

Comment: No you cant give in percentage

Comment: No you can't.. But if you tell me the reason why are u doing in this way, then hopefully I may help you..

Comment: i want to maintain content to 100% for responsive site

Comment: @user2389411: Use css property [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) like this `box-sizing:border-box; width:100%; padding: 1%; border:1px solid #000;` See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp8qY/) I hope this is the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you can not add percentage `border-width`, you can instead of that add `linear-gradient` or `padding` or `magin` and make that space of the `padding` or `margin`'s color same as the color of the border that you want